# MySQL scheduler

Tags: mysql, event-scheduler

Every time I restart the MySQL server, the event scheduler gets dissabled.

I can't find any variable in the my.cnf to enable this, does anyone know a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [event_scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler) option.

You can start it with:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

You have to add:

```
event_scheduler=ON
```

to the `/etc/my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` section for permanent.